# POST http://localhost:30001 404 (Not Found) in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Set up an api with nodejs and used it with reactjs. It works pretty well on my windows environment, but when I moved my project to linux environment, I get error: POST http://localhost:3001, 404 (Not Found).

It happened when I tried to access the signup route and signup.

My SignUp:

```
  axios.post(config.serviceUrl+"/auth/signup", form).then(res => {
        if(res.data.success)
        {
          toast("Verification link sent to your mail id. Please verify.")
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        if(err.response){
          toast(err.response.data.message)
        }else{
          toast("Please check your internet connection! ")
        }
      })
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
      if (err.message) {
        toast(err.message)
      } else {
        toast("Something went wrong!")
      }
    }
```

My ENV PORT:

```
ENV: PORT=3001
```

My Dev Config

```
require('../boot');

module.exports = {
    dbUri: process.env.DBURI,
    jwtSecret: process.env.JWTSECRET,
    cookieKey: process.env.COOKIEKEY,
    mailService: process.env.EMAIL_SERVICE,
    mailHost: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    mailPort: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
    mailSecure: process.env.EMAIL_SECURE,
    mailUser: process.env.EMAIL_AUTH_USER,
    mailPassword:  process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    expires: process.env.EXPIRESIN ,
    port: process.env.PORT
};
```

Main Config Setup

```
module.exports = {
    serviceUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
}
```

my router

```
const router = new express.Router();
const jwtIgnorePaths = ['/login', '/signup'];
```

How I used the port in my .ENV Reactjs end

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001
```

Again, when I made a request to the signup api, I get a return response with 404 not found with a URL below:
http://localhost:3001//auth/signup
I dont know where the double slash is coming from.

*NOTE: It's works fine on my windows machine.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give complete details in the question, there are some items missing like config.serviceUrl....

Comment: @SAR, I have updated added my main config code that content the serviceURL

Comment: Your config shows you're using port 3001, so why are you trying to post to port 3000? Also I don't see a single `app.post` in the code you're showing that demonstrates there will be a handler there for when you use the correct port.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have updated the title to 3001, it was a mistake due to I copied the title from another stackoverflow and forgot to change the last value. Also, it is axio.post on the MY SIGNUP code above.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, 

Again, when I made a request to the signup api, I get a return response with 404 not found with a URL below:
http://localhost:3001//auth/signup
I dont know where the double slash is coming from, as I have checked all my codes without finding the double slash error root.

Comment: If the error happens on that axios line (which you've not made clear in your post: is this a server side or client side error? Please [show the actual error](/help/how-to-ask)), I'm pretty sure it's because `config.serviceUrl` already ends on a slash? But find out: console.log that value to see what's in it.

Comment: Yes @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is correct.
@blcdev that's why I asked you to make sure with config.serviceUrl 
even in this case, you can try by removing slash from (before auth) `axios.post(config.serviceUrl+"/auth/signup", form)`

Comment: Also, one way to make things like this a little less weird is to use templating strings, e.g. ```axios.post(`${config.serviceURL}/auth.signup`, form)```, which would make it pretty obvious where additional slashes are coming from.